# Decorators in Python

Tags: python

I am just learning python, and I am currently playing with Tornado framework. I see this class:

```
class AuthHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.GoogleMixin):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        if self.get_argument("openid.mode", None):
            self.get_authenticated_user(self.async_callback(self._on_auth))
            return
        self.authenticate_redirect()
```

I am having trouble grasping what the decorator does there (@tornado.web.asynchronous). Does it overwrite that function?

You can see the full source at https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/chat/chatdemo.py

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it probably does, but it *proprably* retains a reference to the original `get(self)` definition.

Python decorators are nothing more than a callable themselves (a function, or a class instance with a `__call__` method). Whatever *that* callable returns is used as the definition for the decorated function instead.

If I define a simple no-op decorator like this, that means that I replace the original with.... the original:

```
def noopDecorator(func):
    return func
```

The `@` symbol used for decorators is syntactic sugar, you could also write it as:

```
class AuthHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.GoogleMixin):
    def get(self):
        if self.get_argument("openid.mode", None):
            self.get_authenticated_user(self.async_callback(self._on_auth))
            return
        self.authenticate_redirect()
    get = tornado.web.asynchronous(get)
```

In the case of the tornado `asynchronous` decorator, the decorator probably returns a deferred handler, to handle the decorated function asynchronously, keeping you, the programmer of a tornado-based application, from having to remember the intricacies of how to do that, time and again. In short, it let's you focus on the details of your application instead.

Comment: That alternate syntax makes sense to me to see how decorators work, thank you. I also found this answer later on stack overflow and it helped also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators

Answer (score 0):

You can see the documentation for `@tornado.web.asynchronous` can be found here http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/web.html#tornado.web.asynchronous.

But basically it means that the method will be run asynchronously if possible.